# Form from .load() checkbox and file input not working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

With Ajax, I load a form inside my page. In this form, there are also file inputs, checkboxes and a submit button. With this I get the form to submit:

```
$(WrapperDiv).on('click', SubmitButton, function(){...})
```

I get the form to submit. Like that I can also change the checked attribute of the checkbox, but not the appearance of it. And the file input doesn't open a file dialog. So how does it work with these two?

[image]

The Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-outer add-outer" id="add-outer">
    <div class="add-inner" id="add-inner">

    </div>
</div>
```

What ajax loads (Django):

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'wiki:add' typ %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <legend>{{ typ|capfirst }} hinzufügen</legend>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    </fieldset>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="form-btn">Senden</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add-btn').on('click', function(){
        url = $(this).attr('data-url');
        $('#add-inner').load(url, function(form){
            $('#add-inner .datepicker').datepicker()
            $('#add-inner textarea').tinymce({
                theme: "modern",
                height: 100,
            })

            $('#add-inner').hide()
            $('#add-outer').fadeIn()
            $('#add-inner').slideDown()
            $('#add-inner').css('left', (($(window).width()-$('#add-inner').width())/2))
        })
    });
    $('.add-outer').on('click', function(){
        $('.add-outer .add-inner').slideUp('fast');
        tinyMCE.remove();
    })
    $('#add-inner').on('click', 'input[type=checkbox]', function(){
        console.log(this, 'click')
        $(this).attr("checked", !$(this).attr("checked"));
    })
    $('#add-inner').on('click', '#form-btn', function(){
        form = $('#add-inner form')
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                if(response == 1){
                    $('#add-inner').slideUp()
                    $('#add-outer').fadeOut()
                }

            }
        })
    });


    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('#add-inner').css('left', (($(window).width()-$('#add-inner').width())/2))
    });
})
```

Comment: It looks like the inputs are disabled. See if there is a matching CSS rule.

Comment: No, it's not disabled. All normal inputs in the form can be used as normal and I even can drag a document inside the file input. And I can't find a CSS rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Damn. I found the problem. The inner div with the form inside is packed inside an outer div and this div is reused from another part of the website. And in another .js file, I do this:

```
$('.form-outer').on('click', function(){
    $(this).fadeOut()
}).children().on('click', function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

And that leads to a problem, because this script blocks all child-events of the outer div. So this was pretty stupid of me. I hate it. ^-^